# Geolocation options

Tags: html, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm planning a site where content on the landing page is determined by the geographical location of the user. The accuracy doesn't need to be pinpoint, within a UK post code would be perfect less accurate isn't a huge problem. I'm looking at cross-browser compatibility here mainly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Cultural note: A UK postcode is about 10 / 15 houses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try html5 Geo Location: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html

Here is a demo page which you can take the code from: http://html5demos.com/geo

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a server-side solution, I recommend [GeoIP/GeoLite](https://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite) from MaxMind. It has a clean, simple, and efficient API, although its primary documentation seems to be just in the the header files. If you want more accuracy later, the paid version of the database can be substituted for the free version simply by replacing the database file (without code changes).